# Start List at the bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2. I have a list of items:

```
this.firelist = this.dataService.findMessages(this.chatItem).map(items => {
  this.updateReadMessages(items);
  return items.reverse();
});
```

Displayed in a list:

```
<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
  <ion-list class="message-list">
    <ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
        ....
```

This works, but as you can see, I have a reverse list. So the latest item is at the bottom. As a result, I would like to start the display at the bottom.

I have tried:

```
window.setTimeout(()=> {this.content.scrollToBottom();}, 2000);
```

This works, but there is a delay on the scroll, and visually the scroll doesn't look as good as if the list could just start at the bottom, and not have to scroll.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will find a very elegant solution for this, but you can try the following:

Try using [**`ionViewWillEnter`**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/):

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
```

---

You could also try bind to the last item of your `ngFor` and then fire the scroll as the last item is rendered. Something similar to this:

```
<ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async; let last = last">
    {{ item }}
    {{ last ? doScroll() : '' }}
</ion-item>
```

In your component:

```
export class somePage{
  ...
  constructor(...) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.items[i] = i
      }
    }, 300)
  }
  doScroll(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
}
```